# polymer build needs github connection

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, polymer-starter-kit, polymer-cli

When i am trying to build my polymer application via polymer-cli, it tries to connect to github. But i have already downloaded and installed all dependencies and application runs without any issue with polymer serve.

I want to build the polymer app without github connection. Is it possible?If possible where can i disable attempting github connection? If not possible can anyone please explain why it is needed because all dependencies are already installed.

Error:-

```
Promise rejection: Error: Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/PolymerElements
```

Comment: `polymer serve` runs the local web server, instead try to use `polymer init` to initialize polymer to recent directory. You do not need to be connected to github while implementing an app here below link may help  https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli

Comment: I don't have any problem with polymer serve. It works perfect. Problem is with polymer build. polymer build needs always connected to github.

Comment: Sorry, I got you wrong at first, I have built and tested many polymer apps, but sometimes dependency problems not solved easy. Instead I suggest you to create new dir and init polymer again.

Comment: Due to search internet this command for git con. may work and solve the problem `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is built in functionality. Whenever you build, it wants to make sure it has the most up to date components. I'm not sure if there is any way to turn it off.